# Hibernate delete orphan

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a parent child relationship between 2 classes

Parent

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PARENT")
public class Parent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;


    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "WAGES")
    private BigDecimal wages;


    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID")
    private List<Child> children;   

    // getters and setters

    }
```

Child

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CHILD")
public class Child{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "PARENT_ID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long parentId;

    // getters and setters
}
```

In this particular case, there are no child records for the parent. When I update the parent , hibernate throws the following exception even though the parent does not contain any child records and I am not trying to update/add/remove any child records. The children collection is not accesses at all in code. I am using all JPA annotations. Hibernate version is 3.6.7.Final. Any pointers is appreciated.

org.hibernate.HibernateException: A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance:com.mycode.Child

//Service code

```
public Parent update(ParentDto dto) {
        Parent parent = parentDao.findById(dto.getId());    
        // Using Dozer to map dto object to entity object
        // http://dozer.sourceforge.net/
        dozerMapper.map(dto, parent);       
        taxFormW2Dao.saveOrUpdate(parent);
        return Parent;
    }
```

// Dao code

```
public void saveOrUpdate(Parent parent){
        // HibernateTempplate is injected through Spring
        HibernateTemplate template = getHibernateTemplate();
        getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(parent);    
    }
```

Comment: Can we see the code which does the update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the dozerMapper does something with the collection. Try copying the fields from the DTO to the entity without using dozer.

Moreover, saveOrUpdate takes a detached instance, and attaches it to the session. It throws an exception if the attached version of the detached entity is already loaded in the session.

The parent passed to `saveOrUpdate` is already attached, and the call to `saveOrUpdate` is thus completely unnecessary (and could cause an exception). Changes made to an attached entity are automatically persisted by Hibernate. You don't need to call `saveOrUpdate`, `update` or `merge`.

Comment: Hi JB Nizet. Thanks removing the dozer mapping did the trick.